# count value in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cart that I need to add a product more than once

for example :
2x milk
3x  dresses
and etc...

but when I adding the item to the cart it's multiple its self,

for example :

1xmilk

2 x milk
2 x milk

3 x milk
3 x milk
3 x milk

I need to count its time the item add to the cart, but my code doesn't work.

---code---

my data :

```
const Products_List = {
  Ingredients: ["apples", "eggs", "coffee", "milk", "suger"],
  Clothes: ["shoes", "t-shirt", "dresses", "pants", "jacket"],
  Home_Products: ["broom", "mop", "battreis", "Wipes", "Cleaners"],
};
```

functions :

```
  const addItemToList = (item) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  const deleteItemFromList = (item) => {
    let arr = [...cart];
    let list = arr.filter((x) => x !== item);
    setCart(list);
  };
```

my cart :

```
    <ul>
      <h4 style={{marginRight : "20px"}}>Cart List</h4>
      {cart.map((item) => {
        let count = cart.filter((x) => x === item).length;
        return <li>{`${count} X ${item}`}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you are looping over the `cart` variable and then creating a new element for each item in it. Because you are representing, for example, ten apples by having ten items in your array, ten elements will be created. To prevent duplicate elements from being created, you need to get the unique items in the array and then render an element for each instead. By using sets, you can filter out the duplicates. You should replace the "my cart" section of your code with this:

```
<ul>
  <h4 style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}>Cart List</h4>
  {[...new Set(cart)].map((item) => {
    let count = cart.filter((x) => x === item).length;
    return <li>{`${count} X ${item}`}</li>;
  })}
</ul>
```